# Concatenate two columns in excel and insert into sql server using SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

Greetings!

I have created an SSI package with Excelsource,Dataconversion,lookup, and Oledbdestination . Using this i am able to insert the data from excel to sqlserver. I have got new requirement like, in excelsheet i have id,firstname,lastname,..etc... I have a table in sqlserver with columns, id,name, etc.. Requirement is concatename firstname and lastname together and then insert into sqlserver.
How can i acheive this via SSIS. Please any suggessions.

Regards
Sangeetha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `Derived Transformation` .Create a `New Derived Column Name` and in the expression simply `concatenate` the 2 columns

```
FirstName + LastName
```